# How do you say "My skills in programming languages are Javascript, Zend framework, Yii framework, etc"?

Tags: translation

How do you say:

> My skills in programming languages are Javascript, Zend framework, Yii framework, etc

I have tried this:

> 私のスキルはプログラミング言語で。

And I don't know how to list the items "Javascript, Zend framework, Yii framework, etc", especially how to place the particles.

Comment: How about 言語XでのレベルはZ急です? It's a difficult question to answer as everybody will have a different answer for you...

Comment: I don't get it why did you say this is difficult and possible to has different answers ?

Comment: Do you mean A, B, C, and D are different programming languages, or they are concepts of programming (OOP, AI, Web applications, etc.)?

Comment: I meant that's just for example purpose. In fact I want to write it as "Zend framework,Yii framemwork, JQuery framework, Javascript, etc". because I only need the pattern to learn the grammar.

Comment: Is "[Listing multiple nouns](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/multiple_nouns)" what you need? And "skill in programming language" is "プログラミング言語のスキル".

Comment: @mockie, it's a translation so you can translate it in several possible ways which will convey the same meaning. By the way, just realised that I used the wrong kanji it should be 級 instead of 急.

Comment: By the way, don't insist on using the I in Japanese. The Japanese don't say 私 that often as it's usually implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - X, Y, Z言語が使えます。
> - X, Y, Z言語で開発が出来ます。
> - X, Y, Z言語でソフト構築が出来ます。
> - 言語X, Y, Zのプロです！
> - プログラミング言語はいくつか使えます。

There are a lot of possible translations, so just pick one. But I'm sure somebody else will offer a better translation soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will wait another possible answers before I accept your answer :)

Comment: `構築` indicates physical construction or building, so I don't think it would be used in relation to software development.  Unless this is some set phrase or 専門用語 that I've never heard before.

Comment: @istrasci unless I completely misunderstood what was being said to me at work, you can use it in software development.

Comment: @yu_ominae:  I think I found some examples of that after I posted the comment.  I stand corrected.

Comment: @Itrasci, I actually started doubting what I'd said this morning and also whether I'd used it correctly, so thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 3):

My $0.02.

> - プログラミング言語のうち、X、Y、Zが(専門・得意)です。
> - ソフト開発にかけて、得意とする言語はX、Y、Zです。

Comment: What's exactly translation of this "My skills in programing languages are A, B, C and D." ? Is this correct "私のプログラミング言語でのスキルはＡ，Ｂ，Ｃ，とＤです。" ?

Comment: Yes, that is a literal translation. But it sounds really weird. To be honest your sentence in English sounds weird to start with...

Comment: +1 for the very natural first sentence alone.  In the second, 「手際のよい」 would have to be changed to something like 「得意とする」.

Comment: No worries. I assume you're trying for a job interview, so good luck!

Comment: @yu_ominae no, I'm not. I have just started to learn Japanese and It's totally for learning purpose because I don't know what to write so I am trying to write my profile in Japanese :)